# Manual vs GC memory management in Interpreter & using malloc/free

Tags: c, memory-management, compiler-construction, garbage-collection, malloc

A newbie-sounding question from somebody with 25 years of coding experience.

So, please, before you quickly answer, read on. :)

---

I'm currently **writing an interpreter** (basically a Bytecode Stack VM one) for a programming language I have designed myself. The whole codebase is in C. (after 2-3 rewrites in different languages, ranging from D to Nim)

- why did I finally end up in C? because what matters to me the most is performance and having full control over everything
- why didn't I do it earlier? because I was afraid I would be lost in a sea of memory leaks

---

Long story short, I'm trying to find out what the best approach would be, always having optimum performance as a goal.

I have experimented with Boehm's GC. Basically, use `GC_malloc` (or `GC_malloc_atomic`) whenever I allocate memory and `GC_free` whenever I want to free it.

This gave my interpreter a 10% speed boost in several benchmarks I'm running.

And this confused me.

Is it because Boehm's `GC_free` simply does nothing (until it actually does)?

Now, I decided turning the GC off and doing it all manually. Every malloc with its free, and that's it. The memory consumption dropped (which I guess is explained by Boehm not previously free-ing anything). But the performance dropped as well.

So, I decided to experiment with a... different malloc. In this case, [rpmalloc](https://github.com/mjansson/rpmalloc). And the performance improved again.

Am I missing sth?

**And since you are probably confused about what the question is:**

- Does using a GC (like Boehm's) make any sense in an interpreter?
- Does experimenting with different `malloc`s make sense - in terms of improving a Bytecode intepreter's performance
- What are other things that you would recommend in my case? (memory-management optimization-wise and memory allocations)

Comment: Improve the algorithms and the need for memory allocation/freeing/etc.

Comment: I don't understand your questions. You are designing something and asking if using a particular library makes sense. It makes sense, if it suits you and your needs and your design goals. Using a garbage collector is not tied to writing an interpreter. An interpreter can be written without a garbage collector. So you discovered that using different implementations of something improve the "performance" of your application. That's great, use them, take the libraries and optimize the application for your specific use case.

Comment: I'm a bit confused that you could just switch between GC and malloc+free like that. Is your language garbage collected or not? If it is, how exactly did your GCless version of the interpreter work? I'm assuming it didn't just leak memory since you mentioned freeing memory. If the language isn't GCed, then what were you using the GC for? I wouldn't imagine that a VM-based interpreter would create much garbage that doesn't belong to the interpreted language.

Comment: GC makes sense in an interpreter. Ruby uses that, for example, and most lisps are interpreterish. You may find that malloc works well, or an arena/slab allocator. YMMV, basically. There's no single truth here.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, probably on the verge of off topic on this site.

There are different approaches to garbage collecting in an interpreted environment, but which technique fits your requirements best depends heavily on the semantics of your language.

You insist on performance, but there is no absolute measure of performance: do you need very low latency, which would make classic mark and sweep gc inadequate, or do you want better average performance on long tasks? In this case, generating machine code and reducing memory allocation will improve performance much more than tweaking garbage collection methods.

The most difficult task in garbage collection is to get it to work correctly in the first place. You could use reference counting for some simple objects such as strings and bignums and more advanced techniques for others that may have cycles.

You can look at [QuickJS](https://bellard.org/quickjs/) which I co-authored with Fabrice Bellard for a hybrid approach with reference counting and cycle detection.

Can you give a pointer to more details about your programming language?

Comment: I suppose I found it: https://github.com/arturo-lang/arturo

Comment: That's correct. Although the code in question is not yet public and - as you may guess - it's quite difficult to post any "relevant" source code from a 10k-line project. The programming language is expression-based (everything is an expression and returning a value) with lexical scoping, *not* object-oriented, and rather on the functional side of the spectrum (without insisting on Haskell's "purity"). Basically, think of it as a Rebol-influenced syntax, functional language with a touch of Ruby.